# Google Maps Api v3: How to change the Default waypoint markers in the Directions (set)Panel?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, directions

How do you change the markers with custom markers active in the map in the directions panel and change the color aswell from the body? Any help much appreciated.

The screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYFoc.png

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Longer answer: don't use the directions panel. Create your own, with the information you need (from the directions service response) and add your custom markers.

Comment: Thanks, i think it's indeed better to make an new panel, but it's very annoying the default panel can't be customized that easy, only the color of the background can be customized, but like i said, the markers and the little border stays the same.

Comment: It's not that hard to get the information you need from the response and parse it in a panel of your own. For a very basic implementation, have a look at the `writeDirectionsSteps` function here: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/rat1fkkc/

Comment: @MrUpsidown Many Thanks, some useful code explained in a simple way!

Answer (score 4):

Just to keep alive @MrUpsidown comment and code alive:

> Short answer: you can't. Longer answer: don't use the directions
>   panel. Create your own, with the information you need (from the
>   directions service response) and add your custom markers.

[Nov 24 at 16:32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101782/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-change-the-default-waypoint-markers-in-the-directions#comment42721997_27101782)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/rat1fkkc/)

```js
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var routeBounds = false;
var overlayWidth = 200; // Width of the overlay DIV
var leftMargin = 30; // Grace margin to avoid too close fits on the edge of the overlay
var rightMargin = 80; // Grace margin to avoid too close fits on the right and leave space for the controls

overlayWidth += leftMargin;

var start = new google.maps.LatLng(3.148173, 101.7148792);
var end = new google.maps.LatLng(3.1347725, 101.6893408);

function initialize() {

    var btn1 = document.getElementById('calcRoute');
    btn1.addEventListener('click', calcRoute);

    var btn2 = document.getElementById('offsetMap');
    btn2.addEventListener('click', offsetMap);

    var btn3 = document.getElementById('fitAndOffsetMap');
    btn3.addEventListener('click', fitAndOffsetMap);

    var btn4 = document.getElementById('fitMap');
    btn4.addEventListener('click', fitMap);

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        draggable: true
    });

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: start,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        }
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function offsetMap() {

    if (routeBounds !== false) {

        // Clear listener defined in directions results
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'idle');

        // Top right corner
        var topRightCorner = new google.maps.LatLng(map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(), map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng());

        // Top right point
        var topRightPoint = fromLatLngToPoint(topRightCorner).x;

        // Get pixel position of leftmost and rightmost points
        var leftCoords = routeBounds.getSouthWest();
        var leftMost = fromLatLngToPoint(leftCoords).x;
        var rightMost = fromLatLngToPoint(routeBounds.getNorthEast()).x;

        // Calculate left and right offsets
        var leftOffset = (overlayWidth - leftMost);
        var rightOffset = ((topRightPoint - rightMargin) - rightMost);

        // Only if left offset is needed
        if (leftOffset >= 0) {

            if (leftOffset < rightOffset) {

                var mapOffset = Math.round((rightOffset - leftOffset) / 2);

                // Pan the map by the offset calculated on the x axis
                map.panBy(-mapOffset, 0);

                // Get the new left point after pan
                var newLeftPoint = fromLatLngToPoint(leftCoords).x;

                if (newLeftPoint <= overlayWidth) {

                    // Leftmost point is still under the overlay
                    // Offset map again
                    offsetMap();
                }

            } else {

                // Cannot offset map at this zoom level otherwise both leftmost and rightmost points will not fit
                // Zoom out and offset map again
                map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
                offsetMap();
            }
        }
    }
}

function fromLatLngToPoint(latLng) {

    var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
    var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(), map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng());
    var worldCoordinateNW = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(nw);
    var worldCoordinate = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);

    return new google.maps.Point(Math.floor((worldCoordinate.x - worldCoordinateNW.x) * scale), Math.floor((worldCoordinate.y - worldCoordinateNW.y) * scale));
}

function calcRoute() {

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            // Define route bounds for use in offsetMap function
            routeBounds = response.routes[0].bounds;

            // Write directions steps
            writeDirectionsSteps(response.routes[0].legs[0].steps);

            // Wait for map to be idle before calling offsetMap function
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {

                // Offset map
                offsetMap();
            });

            // Listen for directions changes to update bounds and reapply offset
            google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function () {

                // Get the updated route directions response
                var updatedResponse = directionsDisplay.getDirections();

                // Update route bounds
                routeBounds = updatedResponse.routes[0].bounds;

                // Fit updated bounds
                map.fitBounds(routeBounds);

                // Write directions steps
                writeDirectionsSteps(updatedResponse.routes[0].legs[0].steps);

                // Offset map
                offsetMap();
            });
        }
    });
}

function writeDirectionsSteps(steps) {

    var overlayContent = document.getElementById("overlayContent");
    overlayContent.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {

        overlayContent.innerHTML += '<p>' + steps[i].instructions + '</p><small>' + steps[i].distance.text + '</small>';
    }
}

function fitMap() {

    if (routeBounds !== false) {

        map.fitBounds(routeBounds);
    }
}

function fitAndOffsetMap() {

    if (routeBounds !== false) {

        map.fitBounds(routeBounds);
        offsetMap();
    }
}

initialize();
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#map-canvas {
    height:450px;
    width:950px;
}
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 450px;
    background: black;
    opacity: .8;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
#overlayContent {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
#overlayContent p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 6px 0;
}
#overlayContent small {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    font-style: italic;
}
small {
    font-size: 9px;
}
i {
    color: lightblue;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 12px;
}
button {
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="overlayContent">
         <h1>DIV OVERLAY</h1>

         <h5>Routes should not be drawn below this element.</h5>

         <h5>Click the <i>Calc route</i> button to draw the directions route.</h5>

         <h5><i>Map offset</i> will be applied automatically.</h5>

         <h5><i>Drag the route</i> to see how it is applied.</h5>

         <h5>Click the <i>Offset map</i> button to reapply the offset.</h5>

         <h5>Click the <i>Fit only</i> button to only fit route bounds.</h5>

         <h5>Click the <i>Fit and offset map</i> button to fit to route bounds and reapply offset.</h5>

    </div>
</div>
<button id="calcRoute">Calc route</button>
<button id="offsetMap">Offset map</button>
<button id="fitMap">Fit only</button>
<button id="fitAndOffsetMap">Fit and offset map</button>

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
```